# Chaining jquery append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to figure out how I can chain multiple append into my markup. Basically after appending an element, I would like the next element to append it to the first appended element. I hope what I'm saying makes sense.

If you take a look at my code, I just appended the element `<ul class="menu" />` into the element `#footer .research-centers-menu .research`.

Then on the next code I'm trying to insert/append the variable `centers` to the `<ul class="menu" />`

The current output right now doesn't insert the element but places it outside instead. Apologies for my bad english and explanation

```js
var researchCenters = $('a[href$="/items"]').next().clone(),
  centersList = $('li', researchCenters),
  centers = centersList.slice(0);


var research = $('#footer .research-centers-menu .research').append('<ul class="menu" />');

$(research).append(centers);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="aim/items"></a>
    <ul>
      <li>item one</li>
      <li>item two</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<div id="footer">
  this is a footer
  <div class="research-centers-menu">
    <div class="research">

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cause of your appending issue is because `append()` returns the original element, not the appended element.

To make your code work you could invert the logic so that you create the new `ul`, then use `appendTo()`. This will retain the reference required to append the `li`. Try this:

```js
var researchCenters = $('a[href$="/items"]').next().clone(),
  centersList = $('li', researchCenters);

var $research = $('#footer .research-centers-menu .research');
var $ul = $('<ul class="menu" />').appendTo($research);
$ul.append(centersList);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="aim/items"></a>
    <ul>
      <li>item one</li>
      <li>item two</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<div id="footer">
  this is a footer
  <div class="research-centers-menu">
    <div class="research"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Question, what is the purpose of adding `$` on the variable?

Comment: It's just a naming convention to show that the variable holds a jQuery object.

Answer (score 1):

try to append like this.

```
var researchCenters = $('a[href$="/items"]').next().clone(),
  centersList = $('li', researchCenters),
  centers = centersList.slice(0);


var research = $('#footer .research-centers-menu .research')
var ul =$('<ul class="menu" />').append(centers);
research.append(ul);
```

Comment: This appends the `ul` and `li` elements as children of the `.research`, so the `li` will not be children of the new `ul`